# Regular expression for URL filter that makes it hard to read the filterd URL

Tags: regex

I want to insert a URL filter and I would like the URL to be hard to dechiffre.
For example `.*porn\.*` in a way maybe that it uses the ASCII code for the letters in hex form .
Of course, the example is obvious and I definately will leave that one as it is ;)
But for the others I would like them to be hard to read!
Thx!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What have you tried?

Comment: have a look at base64 encoding and decoding, that's a simple way of obscuration

Comment: Where is that URL filter? Just put it somewhere a user can't see the regex.

Comment: I've always found that for any reasonably complex regex I get this feature for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_GET function in PHP to pull an ID out of the URL and display it that way, similar to Youtube with their "watch?v=". I recently did one using "[?id=49](http://www.billynair.com/school/musc1010/musicJournal.php?id=49)" (I only have a few pages ATM, I will have about 70 soon). What I did is use a database with a song_id to index the information. I use the same basic layout, but you can use the ID to access information wrapped in PHP so that it doesnt get sent to the browser but will still display the page you want.

Or if you really want it to look crazy, you could use a database using the SHA() or MD5() function to encrypt it. 
and your display will look like /page.php?id=21a57f2fe765e1ae4a8bf15d73fc1bf2a533f547f2343d12a499d9c0592044d4.